# How to pass data from one component to another component and store that data into an array in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

in my dashboard,i am displaying  cards with some content(title & body)and the data is coming from backend api and that data is stores in notes[] array that is present inside the DisplayNotes.vue ,and each card contains some icons if the user clicks on any card [TRASH-icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CJr6.png)(for example: 4th card delete icon),the particular clickedTrashIcon card data should be passed to the DeleteNote.vue component and the data is stored inside the array called Trash which is present inside the DeleteNote.vue component ,please help me to fix this thing

`DeleteNote.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="Trash-section">
    <div v-for="item in Trash" :key="item.id" class="container note">
        <div class="delete-content">
            <h5>{{item.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{item.body}}</p>

            <div class="icons Trash-icons">
                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-trash-restore"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'DeleteNote',
    data() {
        return {
            Trash: [{
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'Fundoo',
                    body: 'Trash component'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'second',
                    body: 'trash'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'second',
                    body: 'trash'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'second',
                    body: 'trash'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'second',
                    body: 'trash'
                },

            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.icons {
    margin-top: 12.2%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.icons .fa-trash-restore {
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.icons .fa-trash:hover {
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.Trash-section {
    margin-top: 5%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: space-around;
    gap: 10px;
}

.container {
    width: 22%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-right: -15%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #e0dede;
    float: left;
}

.container:hover {
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgb(199, 199, 199);
}

h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 60px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7.5px 10px;
}

.Trash-icons {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.note:hover .Trash-icons {
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

`DisplayNotes.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id" id="blur" class="container note">
        <div @click="toggle(note.id)" class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{note.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="import-icons">
            <icons class="imported-icons note-icons" />
            <button v-if="flag" class="card-button" type="button" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <UpdateNotes :cardId="clickedCard" :cardContent="cardContent" />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
import icons from './icons'
import UpdateNotes from './UpdateNotes.vue'
export default {
    name: 'DisplayNotes',
    components: {
        icons,
        UpdateNotes
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Fundoo',
                body: 'unlimited notes..'
            }, ],
            clickedCard: '',
            cardContent: {},
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayNotes().then(response => {
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
        toggle(id) {
            var blur = document.getElementById('blur');
            blur.classList.toggle('active');
            this.clickedCard = id;
            // this.card.content = this.notes.filter((note) => note.id === id);
            var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
            popup.classList.toggle('active');
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "@/styles/DisplayNotes.scss";
</style>
```

`icons.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="footer">
    <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-palette"></i>
    <i clss="fas fa-image"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-archive"></i>
    <!-- <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i> -->
      <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.footer i {
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: relative;
}

.footer .fa-bell {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.footer .fa-user {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.footer .fa-palette {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.footer .fa-image {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.footer .fa-archive {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

/* .footer .fa-ellipsis-v {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
} */
.footer .fa-trash {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
```

`main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
// import '@/assets/css/main.css'

//vuelidate
import vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

import router from './router'
import './service/axios'
import store from './store';

// import ('./src/Styles/Forget.css')
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(vuelidate)

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Vuex for central state management. The workflow should be like this: you get the data from back-end via api and you store them in a array in your DisplayNotes.vue component and display them. Then you click on the trash icon in the card and get that values from your item from your array. You have to store "deleted item" values in vuex state variable via "Actions" and "Mutations" from vuex. For example "deletedItems". After you did it successfully, you can use "Getters" to get the values from your created variable in vuex store "deletedItems" in every component in your application.

Here is a quick example.
Install vuex at first and import them.

```
npm i vuex
```

create store.js file in the root folder of your application.

in your app.js or main.js etc. you have to import store.js file

`import store from './store';`

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    render: r => r(App)
});
```

put this in your file store.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate"

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [createPersistedState({
    storage: window.sessionStorage,
  })],
  state: {
    deletedItems: [],
  },
  getters: {
    deletedItems: state => {
      return state.deletedItems
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_DELETED_ITEMS(state, value) {
      return state.deletedItems = value
    },
  },
  actions: {
    setDeletedItems({ commit }, value) {
      commit('SET_DELETED_ITEMS', value);
    },
  },
});
```

To set values into a variable:
put this in vue component "DisplayNotes.vue

```
methods: {
   deleteItem(){
     this.$store.dispatch("setDeletedItems", itemValues);
   }
}
```

To get values from vuex:
put this in your "DeletedNotes.vue"

```
import { mapState } from "vuex";

computed: {
    ...mapState(["deletedItems"]),
  }
```

you can use them like:

```
console.log(this.deletedItems)
```

For more check this: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: Hello @Miro Grujin,i am getting the concept of vuex but  i am little bit confusing to pass data

Comment: So... i update my answer, i hope you can understand it a bit better now.

Comment: hello thanks for your answer, now i am going to try this answer @Miro Grujin

Comment: Hello @Miro Grujin, i am getting this type of error 12:8  error  'store' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Comment: i added main.js file  once you can check that one

Comment: You have to use store to :) const app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 store,
 render: r => r(App)
});

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Miro Grujin, it includes lot's of concepts i think it will take some time form me to understand the things

Comment: in my case when ever the user clicks on displayNotes ,Trash icon it will open the DeleteNote.vue component and it will get the data of clicked card based on that details i performed delete operation that's what i needed

Comment: np, you can vote for my answer, if you think it was helpful :)

Comment: is there any other way to acheive this thing by using props

Comment: Yeah i found this thing helpfull, now i am going to vote

Comment: yes, save deleted items i a variable in DisplayNotes.vue a pass as a prop to DeletedNotes.vue. But if you change route, or refresh the sie, you will lose all your items props and values. maybe you store it in the database and call a request on mounted in DeletedItems.vue